# Debugging dockerize ASP.Net Core app in VS Code with live watch

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to set up debugging of dockerize ASP.Net Core WebAPI application inside VS Code. I am able to debug the application.
However, I am not able to set up live watch where whenever a source file is changed in the host, the docker app rebuilds and update the source-map file and reattach the debugger.
Currently, I need to restart the debugging manually every time the source file is changed.

**Folder Structure:**

[image]

**development.dockerfile:**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk as DEV
COPY ["CoreApi.csproj", "src/CoreApi.csproj"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/CoreApi.csproj"
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl unzip
RUN apt-get install -y procps
RUN curl -sSL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh | bash /dev/stdin -v latest -l /publish/vsdbg
ENV DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER 1
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "watch", "run", "--urls=http://+:80"]
```

**.vscode/task.json:**

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "build",
      "command": "dotnet",
      "type": "process",
      "args": [
        "build",
        "${workspaceFolder}/CoreApi/CoreApi.csproj",
        "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
        "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }
  ]
}
```

**.vscode/launch.json:**

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "API Launch (Docker Watch)",
      "type": "docker-coreclr",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "build",
      "dockerBuild": {
        "dockerfile": "${workspaceFolder}/CoreApi/.docker/development.dockerfile",
        "context": "${workspaceFolder}/CoreApi",
        "target": "DEV"
      },
      "appProject": "${workspaceFolder}/CoreApi/CoreApi.csproj",
      "dockerRun": {
        "ports": [
          {
            "hostPort": "5001",
            "containerPort": "80"
          }
        ],
        "volumes": [{ "localPath": "${workspaceFolder}/CoreApi/", "containerPath": "/src" }]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like not possible right now. here is an open issue in vscode-docker github repo about this case.

[[.NET Core Debugging] Debug with dotnet watch](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docker/issues/797)